# Root number of an anticyclotomic twist

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a self-dual Hecke character over a CM field $K$ with root number $-1$. How to show the existence of a finite order anticyclotomic Hecke character $\chi$ over $K$ such that the twist $\lambda\chi$ is self-dual with root number $1$?